# Java twitter4j API returns max tweet size of 140 characters

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using the latest `twitter4j-core 4.0.6`, which was last updated in 2016. Since then, twitter had increased the tweet limit from `140 bytes` to double that.

When calling the `getHomeTimeline()` method,  the max length of the tweets is `140 bytes`.  Is there any way to get the `full text`, are there any updates to the API?

Comment: Are you able to add the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter to the call on getHomeTimeline()?

Comment: thanks, this helped solve the issue.  i ended up instantiating the ConfigurationBuilder with setTweetModeExtended(true)

Comment: ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setTweetModeExtended(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
user = twitter.verifyCredentials();

Comment: I did the 'ConfigurationBuilder() .setTweetModeExtended(true)' option, but I still see "..." at the end of 140 characters for some tweets. Are you sure you are able to display the whole text in the Tweet? Please help. I am using twitter.getUserTimeline to retrieve Tweets.